# Dynamically included file not displayed in Visual Studio C++ 2013 Solution Explorer after at least one filter was created

Tags: visual-studio-2013, filter, msbuild, visual-studio-project

## Introduction

In our project Visual Studio C++ is used as a code editor, while the build is delegated to a GNU make based build system which supports multiple target platforms. The build delegation from Visual Studio to the build system is implemented by a generic MSBuild property sheet, which gets included in every VS project file. (The integration basically works through setting a number of NMake-specific properties, such as `NMakeBuildCommandLine` etc.). The additional job of the generic integration property sheet is the dynamic addition of a project-specific resource file to a project subtree in the Solution Explorer.

The dynamic addition of a project-specific resource file has worked perfectly fine for years both in Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012. Unfortunately, the feature has stopped working in Visual Studio 2013.

## Initial Setup

The following stripped-down example demonstrates the problem. Our minimal setup consists of the following 5 files:

1. `minimal_sample.sln`: solution file, created by VS 2010, with the reference to the project's `Release|Win32`configuration removed (click [here](http://pastebin.com/q8SvhtTN) for the code listing)
2. `minimal_sample.vcxproj`: project file, see detailed description below (click [here](http://pastebin.com/50yZ4nBE) for the code listing)
3. `statically_included_header.h`: minimal example C++ header file (content irrelevant)
4. `statically_included_impl.cpp`: minimal example C++ impl file (content irrelevant)
5. `text_file.txt`: minimal example resource file (content irrelevant)

The `minimal_sample.vcxproj` project file was created as an empty VS C++ 2010 project, after which the following modifications were applied to it:

- the `Release|Win32` configuration was removed
- the statically included files were added using VS 2010 (the section delimited by the  `Start of static file inclusion code` and `End of static file inclusion code` XML comments)
- the MSBuild code section responsible for dynamic resource file addition was added (the section delimited by the `Start of dynamic file inclusion code` and `End of dynamic file inclusion code` XML comments)

The following code listing displays the relevant parts of the `minimal_sample.vcxproj` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <!-- Project file parts left out for brevity -->

  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>

  <!-- Start of dynamic file inclusion code -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TxtFile Condition="'$(TxtFile)'==''">text_file.txt</TxtFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TxtFile)'!='' and exists('$(TxtFile)')">
    <None Include="$(TxtFile)"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- End of dynamic file inclusion code -->

  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />

  <!-- Project file parts left out for brevity -->

  <!-- Start of static file inclusion code -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="statically_included_header.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="statically_included_impl.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- End of static file inclusion code -->

  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

## Manual Steps to Reproduce

As long as no filters are used, the minimal example described above works without problems in any of the Visual Studio versions mentioned in this post, i.e.: VS 2010, VS 2012 and VS 2013.

As soon as a filter is added to `minimal_sample.vcxproj` - no matter whether it is an empty filter, a filter for the statically included files or the dynamically included resource file `text_file.txt` -, the dynamically included resource file gets hidden in Visual Studio 2013 after a restart (or after an *Unload Project* / *Reload Project* sequence). However, the file remains visible in both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012.

As soon as the `minimal_sample.vcxproj.filters` file gets removed, the filters get removed, but the dynamically included resource file `text_file.txt` becomes visible again.

## Questions

1. Is the observed difference in the behaviour of VS 2010/2012 and VS 2013 a bug or a "feature"? Or even a poorly implemented bug fix?
2. Is there a workaround for letting VS 2013 behave as VS 2010/2012 in respect to the dynamically included file?

Comment: I usually work with csproj, so I don't recall filters file, but regarding of what this file filter or not... why you add dynamically files with property? Not just with Items? If you "work with files" you should use ItemGroup

Comment: @Carnifex I agreee, the definition of the _None_ item (through the _TxtFile_ property) seems somewhat artificial. However, it is significant in this case, because that is how the _None_ item gets ultimately set in the original property sheet (remember, I have provided a substantially stripped-down example here). The value of a property similar to _TxtFile_ first has to be dynamically calculated through a series of condition evaluations.